# How to configure my local host database configuration file to work with AWS EC2 distant database?

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I would like to set up my localhost website to work on an AWS EC2 database.

In my configuration file I have to set up the hostname, username, password, db and so on and I don't know what to put under the hostname field. I tried my EC2 public IP (54.214.XXX.XXX) and DNS (ec2-54-214-XXX-XXX.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com)  without success.

How can I set up my localhost website with my distant database hosted on EC2 ? do I have to do something special on the server side ? Am I looking at the right place ?

I'm using phpmyadmin

Thanks

Comment: You'll need to open the security group's port 3306 and tell MySQL to accept connections from remote hosts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get the ec2 api tools and run (where sec-group-id is the security group id associated with your mysql instance)

> ec2-authorize [sec-group-id] -P tcp -p 3306 -s [your-ip-addr]/32

then you will have to fixup the mysql permissioning. add:

> bind-address=0.0.0.0

to your /etc/my.cnf and restart mysql.....

now you must add a mysql user for access to the new database...  drop to your mysql root shell and execute

> grant all on [new-db-name].* to '[your-mysql-user]'@'[your-ip-addr]' identified by '[make-up-a-password]';

then dont forget, mysql needs to reload the permissioning scheme

> flush privileges;

that should be it... your good to go :P

EDIT:

if you have host-based firewalling, you may need to open up tcp/3306.... you can check this by running

> /sbin/iptables -nvL

Comment: Great and detailed answer thanks. I wouldn't have expected it to be so complex. I'll give a try

Comment: mysql is extremely flexible (aka complicated heh).... if you like answer, go ahead and mark it "answered" :D

Comment: yep ! I just want to give a try first :)

Comment: so did you get this to work?  paste a "use mysql; select user, host from user;" if you need more help with this...